# Interpretation of b-splines function in R (from splines library)

Tags: r, splines

I am trying to understand the output of the bs() function from the splines library in R

For a single vector of numbers, I get back several vectors of values, one for each knot.  That makes sense.  However, I'd like to understand how to combine the basis functions to plot the smooth curve representing the original data.

I have a vector of values:

> x
>       [1] 10.89 15.63 16.02 16.59 17.80 22.15 25.38 26.03 27.05 25.50 29.00 27.36 26.49 25.68 50.25 50.29 30.20 26.78 23.69 27.50
>   [21] 26.01 22.73 21.02 17.65

Call the bs function in the splines package:

```
b <- bs(x, degree=6)
```

The output gives a nice matrix of values, with 6 columns, as expected, but the range of values is nowhere near my input.  How to I translate this back to the smooth curve?

```
print(b)
             1            2            3            4            5            6
[1,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.0000000000 0.000000e+00
[2,] 3.802726e-01 1.300124e-01 2.370682e-02 2.431557e-03 0.0001330130 3.031745e-06
[3,] 3.889214e-01 1.455476e-01 2.905006e-02 3.261457e-03 0.0001952877 4.872220e-06
[4,] 3.973729e-01 1.680286e-01 3.789369e-02 4.806989e-03 0.0003252206 9.167941e-06
[5,] 4.012366e-01 2.133383e-01 6.049729e-02 9.649961e-03 0.0008209446 2.909986e-05
[6,] 3.186638e-01 3.187771e-01 1.700749e-01 5.104059e-02 0.0081693963 5.448200e-04
[7,] 2.229004e-01 3.241497e-01 2.514079e-01 1.096819e-01 0.0255205232 2.474190e-03
[8,] 2.040581e-01 3.183676e-01 2.649126e-01 1.239935e-01 0.0309523831 3.219422e-03
[9,] 1.757098e-01 3.054507e-01 2.831947e-01 1.476902e-01 0.0410787127 4.760700e-03
10,] 2.193849e-01 3.232366e-01 2.539995e-01 1.122711e-01 0.0264668055 2.599704e-03
11,] 1.270488e-01 2.701802e-01 3.064326e-01 1.954965e-01 0.0665184058 9.430471e-03
12,] 1.674510e-01 3.006889e-01 2.879689e-01 1.551302e-01 0.0445703424 5.335612e-03
13,] 1.910660e-01 3.130913e-01 2.736260e-01 1.345136e-01 0.0352674345 3.852745e-03
14,] 2.141412e-01 3.217338e-01 2.578054e-01 1.162010e-01 0.0279335674 2.797897e-03
15,] 6.464411e-15 1.590245e-11 2.086402e-08 1.539764e-05 0.0060605126 9.939241e-01
16,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.0000000000 1.000000e+00
17,] 1.013575e-01 2.435557e-01 3.121327e-01 2.250106e-01 0.0865097835 1.385850e-02
18,] 1.830463e-01 3.092945e-01 2.787291e-01 1.412911e-01 0.0381984759 4.302948e-03
19,] 2.733959e-01 3.288974e-01 2.110219e-01 7.615827e-02 0.0146590358 1.175662e-03
20,] 1.637816e-01 2.984218e-01 2.899977e-01 1.585189e-01 0.0462132388 5.613587e-03
21,] 2.046299e-01 3.185754e-01 2.645173e-01 1.235431e-01 0.0307738305 3.193989e-03
22,] 3.019407e-01 3.242905e-01 1.857571e-01 5.985207e-02 0.0102851740 7.364324e-04
23,] 3.490575e-01 3.020117e-01 1.393635e-01 3.617405e-02 0.0050077642 2.888546e-04
24,] 4.016718e-01 2.079735e-01 5.743058e-02 8.920743e-03 0.0007390223 2.550955e-05
ttr(,"degree")
1] 6
ttr(,"knots")
umeric(0)
ttr(,"Boundary.knots")
1] 10.89 50.29
ttr(,"intercept")
1] FALSE
ttr(,"class")
1] "bs"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

Thanks!